# how-to import a module from a package in a sibling directory

Tags: python, module, package

How can I import a variable or function defined in `etc/conf.py`

when my file structure is:

```
code
|-- ctl
|   |-- ctl_interconnect.py
|   |-- __init__.py
|-- etc
|   |-- conf.py
|   `-- __init__.py
`-- __init__.py
```

and I have opened an IPython shell in `ctl` directory ?

The error the I am getting is:

```
In [1]: import code.etc.conf
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-ec5c1bbb6ae5> in <module>()
----> 1 import code.etc.conf

ImportError: No module named etc.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your working directory is `code` in ipython, then you cannot do `import code.etc.conf`. You could do `import etc.conf` since the path up to code is in your system path. You can verify this by doing

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

and the path where `code` is should be the last one.

The reason why you can `import code` but that it can't find `etc` is that you are importing the wrong `code`.

On my system, when I import code, code is the following module (on Windows with Anaconda python distribution):

`<module 'code' from 'C:\\Users\\superCoolUsername\\Anaconda3\\lib\\code.py'>`